# Handling Android Screen Orientation

Tags: android, performance, screen-orientation

I had an issue where my app kept toasting  messages that I had put inside Oncreate() in my main activity which made me think that for some reason my app was restarting due to an exception. After much time I realised that this was happening because I was setting my app to landscape mode. Now that with the orientation change and the activity getting recreated twice, will it double the objects i'm creating and leaving performance issues on my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Activity` will be destroyed, and all it's members will get garbage collected (if there are no other references to them). Therefore, never keep a reference to your `Activity` outside its own scope, or it will not get garbage collected!

Depending on the type of objects you're creating, you can use `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` to save and restore them, obviously. This might speed up things a little (for example, instead of re-reading objects from a database).

Note that this will recreate the objects as well, instead of referring to the same object. It just might be a bit quicker.

Comment: Thanks Niek! But there is an instance where i have stores a reference to the main activity globally. Do you think this would be harmful in this scenario? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you generally want to avoid this. Read up on this in [this article](http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/) from Roman Nurik.